# local/bench earth leakage for testing mains electronics

Tags: testing, earth

I sometimes find myself testing switch mode power supplies and such that I have repaired, and often some undetected fault causes them to trip the earth leakage breaker on the distribution board when plugged in. Can I setup a second local earth leakage on my bench to prevent tripping the whole building?

Comment: Why not simply put an ELCB of greater sensitivity than the ones in the DB, into a power strip that you use? I have separate ELCBs on 2 different circuits in my work area, independent of the building ELCBs.

Comment: And/or use a isolation transformer.

Comment: @jippie With an isotrx, the OP won't know if there is an actual earth leak problem on the repaired equipment.

Comment: Ah that was exactly what I was thinking, ELCB on the bench that will trip first. however, assuming a short circuit condition occurs would both of the CB's trip or just the local one? I guess I would need an ELCB with a higher sensitivity and lower trip current than the building one?

Perhaps an isolating transformer with its own ELCB? would that need its own earth or just the buildings earth then?

Comment: The isolation transformer is a good answer and here's an idea.... If the transformer output is centre-tapped (and fairly balanced) you may be able to use a residual current breaker on the output to detect local imbalances. Just an idea of course. If the output isn't centre tapped then capacitors from isolated power to a centre tap could still do the trick.

Comment: @Rambo If the more sensitive ELCB trips, the others typically will not, barring rare occasions (going by my own set-up).

Comment: @Andyaka: Why on earth would an RCD/ELCB/GFCI need a center tap? It's just measuring the net current through two conductors; if they aren't equal and opposite, it trips.

Comment: @DaveTweed. If the guy uses an isolation transformer without a centre-tap then using caps to create a pseudo centre-tap means he can connect his earth wire to it. If there is a residual imbalance then this should still trip the RCD but it needs the equipments earth wire connected to somewhere like a centre-tap for it to work correctly. I liked your use of the word "earth" LOL

Comment: @Andyaka: But there's no particular reason that this "test earth" needs to be connected to a center tap, pseudo or otherwise. It could just as well be connected to the "test neutral", which would be more representative of an actual installation.

Comment: @DaveTweed if there was a "neutral" to earth fault then connecting the earth wire to neutral wouldn't show that up. Connecting the earth wire to the "centre-tap" would give live or neutral current faults a chance to show themselves thru a more-sensitive RCD. I think this works with or without an isolation transformer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised this question is still lurking around. To definitely avoid tripping the building's earth leakage breaker use a local isolation transformer with a centre-tap on the secondary.

Also use a residual current trip device from the transformer secondary to the SMPSU you are testing. An RCD detects differences in voltages down the two live wires (aka Live and neutral) so you need to wire your SMPSU earth connection to the transformer secondary centre tap.

Should either of the two AC wires have an excessive current to earth the RCD will trip.

If both ac wires have equally excessive fault currents to earth (a less likely scenario) the RCD won't detect anything but neither would the ELCB because the currents balance.

CAUTION - working on live equipment can be dangerous and you need to ensure that the transformer centre-tap (pseudo earth) is grounded locally to protect yourself. However, this may still cause your distribution board's ELCB to trip - however, if you replace that ELCB with an RCD you should be OK.

Comment: An offset tap might have a better chance at catching double faults.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If the OP is serious about it he could have a switch that could connect earth to either wire of the isolation transformer like test (a) or test (b) etc..